# How to verify deployment when deploying frontend and backend using same ingress in EKS cluster

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have my application with frontend in react and backend in java spring-boot. I'm trying to deploy the application in the EKS cluster. Initially I deployed the frontend, there it gave me an alb, from which I can access, the UI. I need to check how and where is my backend deployed and Can I use the backend alb for integration with UI.

I'm adding the ingress.yaml here, if anyone needs to see service, deployment or values.yaml. Let me know.

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "my-app-ingress"
  namespace: "my-namespace"
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}]'
  spec:
   ingressClassName: alb
   rules:
     - host: myapp.aws.com
       http:
         paths:
           - path: /
             pathType: Prefix
             backend:
               service:
                 name: "frontend-service"
                 port:
                   number: 80
           - path: /backend/
             pathType: Prefix
             backend:
               service:
                 name: "backend-service"
                 port:
                   number: 81
```

After adding the steps for backend service, the alb is giving '502 bad gateway'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `ingress` file should looks more like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "my-app-ingress"
  namespace: "my-namespace"
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}]'
  spec:
   ingressClassName: alb
   rules:
     - host: "*.elb.amazonaws.com"
       http:
         paths:
           - path: /
             pathType: Prefix
             backend:
               service:
                 name: "frontend-service"
                 port:
                   number: 80
           - path: /backend/
             pathType: Prefix
             backend:
               service:
                 name: "backend-service"
                 port:
                   number: 81
```

Please note that you provided same `host` for `frontend` and `backend` app so you should add only new `paths`.
Although if you have two different ALB for each service then you should provide explicit domain name for each service.

Comment: I made changes in the ingress, you can see in the latest edit, my ingress look like that. Now how can I test if my backend is running or not. I tried to hit it as 
**myapp.aws.com/backend/** on postman. I just got the response for react app.
`
<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
 <div id="root"></div>
</body>
`

Comment: First stop will be to check `ingress` pod logs and see what message you receive there when you hit backend service with `podman`. Next you can check if `backend-service` name is correct and this service exist. After that it would be useful to check `selector` that `backend-service` is using to find pods. If selector is fine last thing is to check backend app logs and see what is there when request is made. If there is nothing in pod logs we can assume that traffic is not properly routed to backend pod.

Comment: While using two separate alb, one for frontend and one for backend, it works fine. While trying to generate a single alb, /frontend/ works but /backend/ shows 404, whitelabel error page.